# Merging subplots error - 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_gridspec'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Using python 2.7x, cannot upgrade as I'm on a managed windows system. I'm trying to follow this example to merge subplots but return the following error:

> 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_gridspec'

I've taken a look at other examples on here, but cannot find any that work with the build I'm using (Anaconda 2.7, Spyder IDE) Example from:

https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html

```
fig9 = plt.figure(constrained_layout=False)
gs1 = fig9.add_gridspec(nrows=3, ncols=3, left=0.05, right=0.48,
wspace=0.05)
f9_ax1 = fig9.add_subplot(gs1[:-1, :])
f9_ax2 = fig9.add_subplot(gs1[-1, :-1])
f9_ax3 = fig9.add_subplot(gs1[-1, -1])
gs2 = fig9.add_gridspec(nrows=3, ncols=3, left=0.55, right=0.98,
hspace=0.05)
f9_ax4 = fig9.add_subplot(gs2[:, :-1])
f9_ax5 = fig9.add_subplot(gs2[:-1, -1])
f9_ax6 = fig9.add_subplot(gs2[-1, -1])
```

Comment: I have tagged `python` and `python-3.x` as this question and DavidG's answer seems to be something which should be of general awareness for all users

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#new-convenience-methods-for-gridspec) `figure.add_gridspec` was added in matplotlib 3 and above.

For Python 3.5 and above you can simply update matplotlib to the latest version and the example will work. However, matplotlib 3 is not available for Python 2.7 or Python 3.4 and below.

Therefore you can use the old way as described in the [old documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout)

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[:-1, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, :-1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, -1])
```

Comment: Haha, I was just in the edit mode to your answer to add `import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec`

Comment: @Bazingaa thanks anyway. I always forget how to import gridspec so I guess it's an important part!

Comment: Indeed. +1 from me!!

Comment: So that brings up something new - __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'constrained_layout'

I'm taking a look at some other answers now!

Comment: @8556732 I can't reproduce that error. Can you provide the code that gives you the error?